# How to configure SSIS 2005 OLE DB data source component to use sql query from external file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I am using OLE DB data source component as a part of data flow task, but I would like to keep the sql query in an external file and not embedded in the task itself.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a script task in your control flow to extract the sql query from the file and store it in a string variable. You could then use the variable as a source for you ole db data source component.